How would I set up a server on a separate router?
I’m trying to set up a server on a second router. I’m doing this because I want to use a different router for my server and my primary router for my personal devices.
I need to forward a port so that other devices connecting to that port can only connect to my second router.
How would I go about connecting these two routers?

This is usually done using VLANs. You  sound like you are in way over your head so may wish to reconsider.

Perhaps take a few steps back and reconsider what you are actually trying to accomplish here, and then if you cannot find an optimal solution yourself, ask THAT question rather than the one you have asked here that appears based on incorrect assumptions and misunderstandings.
